# Terminating the older instance of a program if a newer instance is started

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, design-patterns, java-threads

Scenario: A program starts a server and listens for another program to connect to said server; if another program connects, kill the server on the old program and start the same server on the new program, and repeat the cycle.

After running the program for the first time, I get:

```
thread started
attempting connection
server started
```

Then, after running the program again, the first instance reads:

```
thread started
attempting connection
server started
Another instance was started, this instance has been shut down
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at me.aj.phoenix.util.JustOneServer.startServer(JustOneServer.java:37)
    at me.aj.phoenix.util.JustOneServer.run(JustOneServer.java:28)
```

and the second instance reads:

```
attempting connection
Another instance was running and has been closed.
server started
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(PlainSocketImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:381)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:243)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:187)
    at me.aj.phoenix.util.JustOneServer.startServer(JustOneServer.java:34)
    at me.aj.phoenix.util.JustOneServer.run(JustOneServer.java:26)
```

Essentially what im trying to do is whenever a new version of the program is started, close the older program and start the listener on the newer program

Here is the code:

```
public class TestProgram extends Thread {
    public final int port = 9665;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("thread started");
        try {
            this.check();
            this.startServer();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            this.startServer();
        }
    }
    public void startServer() {
        try {
            System.out.println("server started");
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, 1);
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            Logger.print("Another instance was started, this instance has been shut down");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void check() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        System.out.println("attempting connection");
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", port);
        if(socket.isConnected()) {
            Logger.print("Another instance was running and has been closed.");
        }
    }
}
```

The second program is not waiting for the first programs listening server to unbind from the port, and I'm not quite sure how to fix it.

Comment: The minimum, you could do, is to `close()` the sockets before proceeding. Even then, you might need to insert a delay to give the other process a chance. But I can’t see any reason for a `NullPointerException` in the posted code.

Comment: I'm pretty certain you can't do that just by using threads and sockets. Closest I can think of is to try and keep some commonly known file around and occasionally check it in a specific daemon thread. When a process starts, it sets some value inside that file (could be anything, even just a last access timestamp). When running server sees that file contains anything, it initiates an orderly app shutdown. Once shutdown is complete, another app can pick up the socket, clear the file and start watching it itself.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the logic in `startServer` method should run in an infinite loop to account for the weak nature of sockets that may be disconnected at any time, and more importantly for the scenario in which is trying to connect to a port that is bound by a previous instance that is in the process of shutting down.

```
        while (true) 
            runServer(port);
```

Other problems include closing resources when problems arise and nesting away the exceptions that arise from a client `Socket` from those that come from a `ServerSocket`; so that whenever an exception is thrown for a `ServerSocket` is not interpreted as an exception that would end the execution of `startServer` method.

```
    void runServer(int port) {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, 1)) {
            logger.debug("Server started!");
            try (Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept()) {
                logger.debug("Signal to shutdown received. Shutting down.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.debug("The other application is still shutting down...");
        }
    }
```

The following is a complete working example of this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class ServerReplacer {
    
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerReplacer.class);
    
    public static void runReplacerService(int port) {
        searchOlderInstances(port);
        
        logger.debug("Server starting...");
        while (true) 
            runServer(port);
    }

    private static void searchOlderInstances(int port) {
        logger.debug("Attempting to find older instance...");
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port)) {
            logOtherInstanceFound(socket.isConnected());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logOtherInstanceFound(false);
        }
    }

    private static void logOtherInstanceFound(boolean otherInstanceFound) {
        logger.debug(otherInstanceFound ? 
            "FOUND ANOTHER INSTANCE RUNNING! It has been signaled to shut down." : 
            "No older instance found.");
    }

    private static void runServer(int port) {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, 1)) {
            logger.debug("Server started!");
            try (Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept()) {
                logger.debug("Signal to shutdown received. Shutting down.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.debug("The other application is still shutting down...");
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runReplacerService(9665);
    }
}
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a56247038)

Hope this helps.